# Question regarding closure of sets defined by the vanishing of holomorphic functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, singularity-theory, gn.general-topology

Consider the following subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ given by
$$ X := \{x \in \mathbb{C}^n: f(x) =0, ~~g(x) \neq 0 \} $$
$$ Y := \{ x \in \mathbb{C}^n: f(x) =0, ~~g(x) =0, ~~h(x) \neq 0 \} $$

where $f, g$ and $h$ are holomorphic functions. 
Let us also assume that $Y$ is non empty. In particular 
this would avoid something like $h(x)$ being a ``factor'' of 
$g(x)$.
Then is it always 
true that

$$ \bar{X} \subset X \cup \bar{Y} $$

where $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ denote the respective closures taken inside $\mathbb{C}^n$?

If this is not true, then is there any reasonable condition on $f$, $g$ and $h$ to ensure that this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Take $n=2$, $f(x,y)=x$, $ g(x,y)=y(y-1),\; h(x,y)=x-y$.